# Aspose Wordsfor .NET: replace link contents keeping (setting) it's style

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

There is much info over internet telling how to change link contents with Aspose Wordsfor .NET. Also, there is enough info about setting link style after insertion.

But I have a problem: I need to modify existed link (from template) keeping (or just setting) it's visual style (underlined blue text). By defaul, after link change (se code below) it's style is broken.

```
foreach (Field field in docTemplate.Range.Fields)
{
    if (field.Type == FieldType.FieldHyperlink)
    {
        var hyperlink = (FieldHyperlink)field;
        if (hyperlink.Result.Equals("<<[model.Id]>>"))
        {
            hyperlink.Address = model.IdUrl;
            hyperlink.Result = model.Id;

        }
    }
}
```

Does any solution for this case exist? Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your scenario with Aspose.Words for .NET 17.4 and unable to notice hyperlink style issue, it remains intact after modification. If you are using some old version of Aspose.Words for .NET then please upgrade to latest version, hopefully it will resolve the issue.

However, if your issue persists then please share your complete code along with your input,output and expected documents. It will help to understand your issue exactly.

I'm Tilal, developer evangelist at Aspose.

```
Document doc = new Document("Hyperlink.docx");
//You may change the color of Hyperlink style, if required.
//doc.Styles[StyleIdentifier.Hyperlink].Font.Color = Color.Blue;
//doc.Styles[StyleIdentifier.FollowedHyperlink].Font.Color = Color.Blue;

foreach (Field field in doc.Range.Fields){
    if (field.Type == FieldType.FieldHyperlink){
        FieldHyperlink link = (FieldHyperlink) field;
        if (link.Result.Equals("aspose.com"))
        {
            link.Result = "google";
            link.Target = "www.google.com";
        }
    }
}

doc.Save("Hyperlink_174.docx");
```

Edit: If you want to modify a specific hyperlink then use following code snippet.

```
Document doc = new Document("E:/Data/Hyperlink.docx");
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

foreach (Field field in doc.Range.Fields)
{
if (field.Type == FieldType.FieldHyperlink)
{
    FieldHyperlink link = (FieldHyperlink)field;
    if (link.Result.Equals("aspose.com"))
    {
        builder.MoveToField(link, false);
        builder.Font.ClearFormatting();

        // Specify font formatting for the hyperlink.
        builder.Font.Color = Color.Blue;
        builder.Font.Underline = Underline.Single;
        // Insert the link.
        builder.InsertHyperlink("google", "http://www.google.com", false);
        link.Remove();
    }
}
}

doc.Save("UpdatedHyperlink.docx");
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll test the latest version. Currently, seen your code, I must mention one difference: I have to change only one given link, leaving other link's styles ontouched.

Comment: I tasted the latest version and yes, it works fine. However, license restrictions let me work with version 16.7, which has incorrect behavior in this case. So the only one way to solve my issue is to define style of individual link changed with `Field field in doc.Range.Fields` code snippet.

Comment: It is recommended to use latest version of Aspose.Words as it includes a lot of improvements and fixes. However I have updated a sample code in above reply to modify a specific hyperlink. You can remove existing hyperlink and add a new with required style.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. But the second version of your code has a problem for me: it inserts new link at the end of current string, but the old link was in the middle. Was "I **did** it", became "I it **did**".

Comment: To fix this problem, you can simply Move link.Remove(); statement to the end of second IF block i.e. after the builder.InsertHyperlink("google", "http://www.google.com", false); statement. Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.